# Update your app to support OAuth 2.0 before 12/13/11

Tags: facebook, oauth

I received two emails from Facebook stating *"Update your app to support OAuth 2.0 before 12/13/11"* and that my apps have not been migrated.  However, I have already migrated my apps to use OAuth tokens months ago, and the emails don't specify which apps so I'm not sure what they are referring to.

The message is from noreply@facebookmail.com so that's why I'm posting a message here. How can I find out why I received this message? I have already followed all of the recommended guidelines for OAuth implementation so I'm a little concerned to be receiving the message.

Answer (score 0):

I received the same message and migrated one of my apps. The othe I haven't is really not working. What you need to do is actually implemente the encrypted oauth_token. What language SDK are you using? If it is Ruby, upgrading your Koala version and passing the extra parameter on FB.init would do the trick.